# How to control for loop to wait till complete a task in each loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am setting validation in each cell in a column base on the value in the cell in column before. My script works as I want if it runs for each cell one by one (no loop). Setting validation in the cell by script and to see the effect take a second or so (I mean obvious slowness). When I put the code into the `for` loop it did not complete the task on some cells, I think due to the time required to finish applying the validation setting on a cell. How can I control the `for` loop to loop next only after the validation setting take effect in the current cell?

I am trying to add dependent dropdown in each cell.

I adopted the code from /http://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/google-sheets-apps-script-dynamic-dependent-dropdown-data-validation-lists/

```
//google scripts for google spreadsheet  

function addDropDown(){
  var tabLists = "Lists";
  var tabValidation = "DATA";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tabLists);
  var datass0 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tabValidation);

  function flatten(arrayOfArrays){
    return [].concat.apply([], arrayOfArrays);
  }

  var dists_in_data = datass0.getRange(5, 2,datass0.getLastRow()).getValues(); //Admin1 in data

  var dists_in_list = datass.getRange(2, 9,datass.getLastRow()).getValues(); //Admin1 in Lists

  dists_in_list = flatten(dists_in_list);
  dists_in_data = flatten(dists_in_data);

  for (var i in dists_in_data){
 //i = 0
    var search_key = dists_in_data[i];   

    var distStart = dists_in_list.indexOf(search_key) + 1;

    dists_in_list.reverse();
    var len = dists_in_list.length;
    var distEnd = len - (dists_in_list.indexOf(search_key) + distStart - 1);
    dists_in_list.reverse();

    //preparing validation list for admin2
    if(distStart != 0){

       var validationRange = datass.getRange(distStart + 1, 10, distEnd );
       var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
       datass0.getRange(i + 5, 3).setDataValidation(validationRule);

     } 

  }

}
```

I expect all cells should have been set with new validation rule.

Comment: A few things... first, please edit your question to provide the full code of your function - not just the snippet; second, would you also please edit your question to include the Execution transcript for a failed processing run; lastly, would you please share your spreadsheet.

Comment: Are you sure your loop gives validationRule for the cells that the script didn't work on? You can try using `Logger.log` to check if the script picked up the correct validation rule.

Comment: As you can see in the [DataValidationBuilder documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinrangerange-showdropdown), the way you are using the method is not specifying that you want the drop-down. The code to create the rule should instead be: `var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange, true).build();` Adding the `true` parameter to the function will force the adding of the drop-down to the intended cells.

Comment: Hi all above, please see the goolge sheet with the script above. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tyWQiqjckQIgKfQRUXXCO1OmEGM4PiX7mLIuy4z8ywc/edit#gid=0

Comment: it works as I wanted if set 'i' with a fix value and the right cell is set with correct dropdown list.

Comment: @KyawNaingWin you mention that if you set the I to a specific value it works, could you show the code you use to do that? Also, the link to your spreadsheet is for read only, so we cannot access the script. you can update your question and paste the whole code.

Comment: @AlbertoMolina I change the permission of the sheet to editable so that you can view the codes.

Comment: I'm seeing the code, I see that column B has the dropdown menu present in the entire column. could you try to run the scrip by changing the validation rule to: `validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange, true).build();`?

Comment: @AlbertoMolina I have removed the dropdown in column B and run as you suggested. But still the same problem. You can test the code by assigning `i` with a value and will see it works.

Comment: On the `var distStart = dists_in_list.indexOf(search_key) + 1;` command, you're finding the position f a particular letter, but each time it seeks out the first appearance of that letter, if you log the values for distStart it behaves like that, it shows you that it always returns the same values, finding the first appearance of A, B, C, D or E in the column.